# Using tensorflow data pipelines for nlp text generator

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, tensorflow2.0, word2vec

I am new to stackoverflow as a question asker.  I am typically perusing for answers on here and have normally never had to ask a question, till now.  I am working on building a deep learning network using the tf.data.Dataset API and the network doesn't seem to be bringing in the dataset correctly.

So to set the stage I am working with a text dataset, I have already broken the text up into tokens, created a dictionary of unique words, created an embedding matrix to convert the tokens into vectors and then planned to use the tf.data.Dataset to enable the easy use of an internal pipeline and batch large datasets to manage training.

The 'vect_doc' variable is an array with shape of (35054, 300).

```
    vect_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(vect_doc)
```

from here I shuffle the dataset so I can break it up into train, test and validation sets.

```
    vect_data_shuffle = vect_dataset.shuffle(len(proc_doc), reshuffle_each_iteration = False)
    
    train_dataset = vect_data_shuffle.take(train_size)
    test_dataset = vect_data_shuffle.skip(train_size)
    val_dataset = test_dataset.skip(val_size)
    test_dataset = test_dataset.take(test_size)
```

Then I batch the datasets to create samples that are 2*sequence_length, I will demonstrate with just the training dataset for simplicity sake.

```
     train_batch_ds = train_dataset.batch(2*self.sequence_length + 1, drop_remainder=True)
```

Once the dataset has been broken up into batches, I run the following process:

```
     def vect_split_dataset(self, sample):
    
         dataset_Xy = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((sample[:self.sequence_length], 
                                               sample[self.sequence_length]))
            
         for i in range(1, (len(sample) - 1) // 2):
        
             X_seq_batch = sample[i: i + self.sequence_length]
             y_nxwrd_batch = sample[i + self.sequence_length]
        
             Xy_samp = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors((X_seq_batch, y_nxwrd_batch))
                    
             Xy_dataset = dataset_Xy.concatenate(Xy_samp)
    
        return Xy_dataset

    Xy_dataset = train_batch_ds.flat_map(train_set.vect_split_dataset)

    Xy_dataset = Xy_dataset.repeat(len(proc_doc)).shuffle(len(proc_doc)).batch(param_dict['batch_size'], drop_remainder=True)
```

The above Xy_dataset returns a shape of ((60, 30, 300), (60, 300)).  Now that I have the dataset created that I can pass to my DNN model is where I start getting problems.  This is the code I am using to build the model:

```
    LSTM = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=self.rnn_units,
                                kernel_initializer=self.initializer,
                                activation=self.activation,
                                recurrent_activation=self.activation_out,
                                return_sequences=True)
    
    for i in range(self.num_layers):
        # Different layers should have different setups as indicated below
        if i == 0: # Initial layer also referred to as the input layer
                         
            self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(input_dim=self.input_dim,
                                                     input_shape=(self.sequence_length, self.spacy_len),
                                                     output_dim=self.spacy_len,
                                                     input_length=self.batch_size))
            
        elif i+1 == self.num_layers: # Output layer
            self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(self.drop_rate))
            self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(units=self.num_units_out,
                                                 kernel_initializer=self.initializer,
                                                 activation=self.activation_out))
            self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation(self.activation_out))
        else: # hidden layers basically anything that isn't an input or output layer
            self.model.add(tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(LSTM))
```

Basically the errors I keep getting is that 'ValueError: Input 0 of layer bidirectional is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 30, 300, 300]'

I am not sure if this is how I am handling the embedding error or what.  When I mute the embedding layer and replace it with the Bidirectional I get an incompatibility error between two shapes (60,300) and (60, 30, 300).

My goal is to make it iterate over the entire dataset in some defined batches (for this example I am using 60) for each epoch.  I have set the steps per epoch to the length of the entire document minus the sequence length divided by the batch size 'steps_per_epoch = (len(processed_doc) - self.sequence_length) // self.batch_size' when calling the model.fit command.

I appreciate any comments or guidance that can be provided on fixing this issue.

Comment: It seems that the input dimension is not matching the shape of your data. Check its `.shape` and verify that your dims are right.

Comment: @JohnStud So the dimensions that I am passing into model.fit  from the data is: ((60,30,300), (60,300)).  Then for the embedding layer of the model, I have it set as: input_dim=length of vocab(2603); output_dim=300, input_shape=(30, 300) input_length=batch_size (60).

Comment: I am not that great with TF (you should try Torch) but it seems to me that TF is saying you are sending it data that is shape `30, 300, 300` hence: `Full shape received: [None, 30, 300, 300]'` I think you have an extra dimension of `300` in there that it does not expect.

Comment: Yeah I am thinking it is due to me trying to use the TF data pipeline pieces, when it creates the dataset it is putting the input and target into a single dataset as different elements.  I am starting to think that when ingested into the keras neural networks it doesn't know there are two separate elements there.